# Transpose Algorithm for Directed Graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, transpose, directed-graph

I am trying to write a simple algorithm to represent a reverse directed adjacency matrix. I want this in  in-place, with running time of Theta(n^2).

At first I had this:

```
for i=1 to n
         for k=1 to n
               //Reverse the edges and update the new adjacency list
                  A_new[k][i] = A_old[i][k]
return A_new
```

However, I realized the inner for loop would cause a problem because if first loop is going 1..n and second going form 1..n, you will need to swap everything twice.

What would the inner for loop have to be to avoid this?

Comment: I don't see a problem...unless you can assume some sort of symmetry or anti-symmetry, you need to inspect all n^2 elements, so the loop should be correct as is.

Comment: @ Jim Lewis  I want the algorithm in  in-place, with running time of Theta(n^2).

Comment: If you want it in place, why do you have A_new and A_old?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine if you're returning a new matrix.  If you want to flip the matrix in place, then you iterate over the upper triangle, and swap each element with the lower triangle like this:

```
for i=1 to n-1
    for j=i+1 to n
        temp = A[i][j];
        A[i][j] = A[j][i];
        A[j][i] = temp;
```